# Angular : block/wait until promise is done

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

In my view, I need to do some extra "form validation" with my backend (called with $http). To abort or trigger the form sending, I need to wait for the promise returned by $http to finish.

```
$('#myForm').submit(function() {
    ...
   $http(...).success(function(data) {
      if (data.condition){
          //send the form by returning true
          return true;
      } else {
          //stay on this page by returning false
          return false;
   });

   //what should I return here ?? 
}
```

In general, how do we wait/block for a promise to finish, such as the one returned by the $http() function?

Comment: You can't. Return `false` always and submit the form data manually using AJAX if your validation allows it.

Comment: The question was more about blocking for a promise than sending the form, so reopen ?

Comment: I think you need to read the accepted answer to that question carefully; see that in that answer, the form is initially never submitted, but if the callback is successful, the callback submits the form `$("#someForm")[0].submit();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promises don't make your code synchronous. AJAX is still asynchronous. You need to asynchronously handle your code.

So validate your code like you would validate with classic AJAX code.

Comment: If the answer is no, please just say no. It's so goddamn frustrating to be searching the internet for an answer, and no one will say it straight.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, the answer would be that should return the promise that was created via `$http`. However in the case of eventHandlers, you can call `preventDefault()` and then `submit()` explicitly.

```
var form = $('#myForm');
form.submit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); // prevent submit
   $http(...).success(function(data) {
      if (data.condition){
          //send the form by explicit submit
          form.submit();
      }
   });
}
```

Note, this works just as well with very minor modifications in new browsers without jQuery.

On a side note, good angular practices discourage this sort of thing - you should put presentation logic in directives and not call DOM methods directly like that. The presentation "does not decide" about the fate of the page. It delegates via `ng-click` to a scope method.